# How can I fetch XML of a record in Netsuite using SuiteScript?

Tags: oracle, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to fetch xml data of a Sales Order record but I can't find a way to do it.
The data appears when we add '&xml=t' to the url of a record.
I want to fetch all the data in XML format into a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe you can. You can check N/xml to see if there are functions there. You can also try ODBC as a work-around. What's your use case? Maybe I can point you in a better direction?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the answer.

Just use record.load and store it in a variable.

```
var objRecord = record.load({
  type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
  id: 157,
  isDynamic: true,
});
```

Logging this varialbe won't help, as there is character limit of 3999 characters. You can store it in File Cabinet.

Comment: this opens record object. how did u get xml through it?

Comment: @curiousKido If you log it, you will get the data in XML format

Comment: it shows in JSON not XML